# Writing with finger/nail

Tags: clothing, paper

I'd like a material I can wrap around my wrist and write on with my finger/nail. My first thoughts are something like suede leather, the sort you'd find on a journal. I also need to be able to erase whatever is on it by wiping it or rinsing under some water etc.

I don't want any tech. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Colin, Welcome to Lifehacks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you ever heard of a Magic Slate?

It's a toy that you can use to make marks which can be "erased" by separating the top layer of plastic from a bottom layer of darker permanent pigment.

[image: Magic Slate toy]

The material is mounted on a decorative card which can be removed for a more formal appearance. Although it comes with a plastic or wooden stylus, you can use anything to make a mark such as your fingernail. It's reusable. Permanent copies can be made on a copier or with a cellphone camera before the content is lost.

If the size of the active area is too large, it can be cut easily with shears or an art knife or even a paper cutter.

When you're bored, you can use it to doodle. The marks appear dark on a light background.

As far a tech goes, it's about as low as you can go and as cheap a solution as you'll find.

Good luck.